# How do I handle fork() correctly with boost::asio in a multithreaded program?

Tags: c++, linux, macos, fork, boost-asio

I'm having some trouble grasping how to correctly handle creating a child process from a multithreaded program that uses Boost Asio in a multithreaded fashion.

If I understand correctly, the way to launch a child process in the Unix world is to call `fork()` followed by an `exec*()`. Also, if I understand correctly, calling `fork()` will duplicate all file descriptors and so on and these need to be closed *in the child process* unless marked as `FD_CLOEXEC` (and thereby being atomically closed when calling `exec*()`).

Boost Asio requires to be notified when `fork()` is called in order to operate correctly by calling [`notify_fork()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/notify_fork.html). However, in a multithreaded program this creates several issues:

1. Sockets are by default inherited by child processes if I understand correctly. They can be set to `SOCK_CLOEXEC` - *but not directly at creation**, thus leading to a timing window if a child process is being created from another thread.
2. `notify_fork()` requires that no other thread calls *any other `io_service` function*, nor *any function on any other I/O object associated with the `io_service`*. This does not really seem to be feasible - after all the program is multithreaded for a reason.
3. If I understand correctly, any function call made between `fork()` and `exec*()` needs to be async signal safe (see [`fork()` documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html#tag_16_156)). There is no documentation of the `notify_fork()` call being async signal safe. In fact, if I look at the source code for Boost Asio (at least in version 1.54), there may be calls to [pthread_mutex_lock](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html), which is *not* async signal safe if I understand correctly (see [Signal Concepts](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04), there are also other calls being made that are not on the white list).

Issue #1 I can probably work around by separating creation of child processes and sockets + files so that I can ensure that no child process is being created in the window between a socket being created and setting `SOCK_CLOEXEC`. Issue #2 is trickier, I would probably need to make sure that *all* asio handler threads are stopped, do the fork and then recreate them again, which is tideous at best, and really really bad at worst (what about my pending timers??). Issue #3 seems to make it entirely impossible to use this correctly.

**How do I correctly use Boost Asio in a multithreaded program together with `fork()` + `exec*()`?**
... or am I "forked"?

Please let me know if I have misunderstood any fundamental concepts (I am raised on Windows programming, not *nix...).

Edit:
* - Actually it is possible to create sockets with `SOCK_CLOEXEC` set directly on Linux, available since 2.6.27 (see [`socket()` documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/2/socket)). On Windows, the corresponding flag `WSA_FLAG_NO_HANDLE_INHERIT` is available since Windows 7 SP 1 / Windows Server 2008 R2 SP 1 (see [`WSASocket()` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). OS X does not seem to support this though.

Comment: Not clear whether you want to just `fork` a clone of your parent process, or `fork` + `exec` another executable.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: I want to do `fork` + `exec`. Tried to make it a bit more clear in the stated question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In a multi-threaded program, [`io_service::notify_fork()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/notify_fork.html) is not safe to invoke in the child.  Yet, Boost.Asio expects it to be called based on the [`fork()` support](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/posix/fork.html), as this is when the child closes the parent's previous internal file descriptors and creates new ones.  While Boost.Asio explicitly list the pre-conditions for invoking `io_service::notify_fork()`, guaranteeing the state of its internal components during the `fork()`, a brief glance at the [implementation](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/boost-1.55.0/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/service_registry.ipp#L61) indicates that `std::vector::push_back()` may allocate memory from the free store, and the allocation is not guaranteed to be async-signal-safe.

With that said, one solution that may be worth considering is `fork()` the process when it is still single threaded.  The child process will remain single threaded and perform `fork()` and `exec()` when it is told to do so by the parent process via inter-process communication.  This separation simplifies the problem by removing the need to manage the state of multiple threads while performing `fork()` and `exec()`.

---

Here is a complete example demonstrating this approach, where the multi-threaded server will receive filenames via UDP and a child process will perform `fork()` and `exec()` to run `/usr/bin/touch` on the filename.  In hopes of making the example slightly more readable, I have opted to use [stackful coroutines](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/spawn.html).

```cpp
#include <unistd.h> // execl, fork
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

/// @brief launcher receives a command from inter-process communication,
///        and will then fork, allowing the child process to return to
///        the caller.
class launcher
{
public:
  launcher(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
           boost::asio::local::datagram_protocol::socket& socket,
           std::string& command)
    : io_service_(io_service),
      socket_(socket),
      command_(command)
  {}

  void operator()(boost::asio::yield_context yield)
  {
    std::vector<char> buffer;
    while (command_.empty())
    {
      // Wait for server to write data.
      std::cout << "launcher is waiting for data" << std::endl;
      socket_.async_receive(boost::asio::null_buffers(), yield);

      // Resize buffer and read all data.
      buffer.resize(socket_.available());
      socket_.receive(boost::asio::buffer(buffer));

      io_service_.notify_fork(boost::asio::io_service::fork_prepare);
      if (fork() == 0) // child
      {
        io_service_.notify_fork(boost::asio::io_service::fork_child);
        command_.assign(buffer.begin(), buffer.end());
      }
      else // parent
      {
        io_service_.notify_fork(boost::asio::io_service::fork_parent);
      }
    }
  }

private:
  boost::asio::io_service& io_service_;
  boost::asio::local::datagram_protocol::socket& socket_;
  std::string& command_;
};

using boost::asio::ip::udp;

/// @brief server reads filenames from UDP and then uses
///        inter-process communication to delegate forking and exec
///        to the child launcher process.
class server
{
public:
  server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
         boost::asio::local::datagram_protocol::socket& socket,
          short port)
    : io_service_(io_service),
      launcher_socket_(socket),
      socket_(boost::make_shared<udp::socket>(
        boost::ref(io_service), udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), port)))
  {}

  void operator()(boost::asio::yield_context yield)
  {
    udp::endpoint sender_endpoint;
    std::vector<char> buffer;
    for (;;)
    {
      std::cout << "server is waiting for data" << std::endl;
      // Wait for data to become available.
      socket_->async_receive_from(boost::asio::null_buffers(),
          sender_endpoint, yield);

      // Resize buffer and read all data.
      buffer.resize(socket_->available());
      socket_->receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(buffer), sender_endpoint);
      std::cout << "server got data: ";
      std::cout.write(&buffer[0], buffer.size());
      std::cout << std::endl;

      // Write filename to launcher.
      launcher_socket_.async_send(boost::asio::buffer(buffer), yield);
    }
  }

private:
  boost::asio::io_service& io_service_;
  boost::asio::local::datagram_protocol::socket& launcher_socket_;

  // To be used as a coroutine, server must be copyable, so make socket_
  // copyable.
  boost::shared_ptr<udp::socket> socket_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::string filename;

  // Try/catch provides exception handling, but also allows for the lifetime
  // of the io_service and its IO objects to be controlled.
  try
  {
    if (argc != 2)
    {
      std::cerr << "Usage: <port>\n";
      return 1;
    }

    boost::thread_group threads;
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    // Create two connected sockets for inter-process communication.
    boost::asio::local::datagram_protocol::socket parent_socket(io_service);
    boost::asio::local::datagram_protocol::socket child_socket(io_service);
    boost::asio::local::connect_pair(parent_socket, child_socket);

    io_service.notify_fork(boost::asio::io_service::fork_prepare);
    if (fork() == 0) // child
    {
      io_service.notify_fork(boost::asio::io_service::fork_child);
      parent_socket.close();
      boost::asio::spawn(io_service,
          launcher(io_service, child_socket, filename));
    }
    else // parent
    {
      io_service.notify_fork(boost::asio::io_service::fork_parent);
      child_socket.close();
      boost::asio::spawn(io_service, 
          server(io_service, parent_socket, std::atoi(argv[1])));

      // Spawn additional threads.
      for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
      {
        threads.create_thread(
          boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));
      }
    }

    io_service.run();
    threads.join_all();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }

  // Now that the io_service and IO objects have been destroyed, all internal
  // Boost.Asio file descriptors have been closed, so the execl should be
  // in a clean state.  If the filename has been set, then exec touch.
  if (!filename.empty())
  {
    std::cout << "creating file: " << filename << std::endl;
    execl("/usr/bin/touch", "touch", filename.c_str(), static_cast<char*>(0));
  }
}
```

Terminal 1:

```
$ ls
a.out  example.cpp
$ ./a.out 12345
server is waiting for data
launcher is waiting for data
server got data: a
server is waiting for data
launcher is waiting for data
creating file: a
server got data: b
server is waiting for data
launcher is waiting for data
creating file: b
server got data: c
server is waiting for data
launcher is waiting for data
creating file: c
ctrl + c
$ ls
a  a.out  b  c  example.cpp
```

Terminal 2:

```
$ nc -u 127.0.0.1 12345
actrl + dbctrl + dcctrl + d
```

Comment: This seems to be the only reasonable way to do this.

Comment: Hi there, just came accross this:
 io_service.run(); will be executed in the parent und child process, is this meant to be?

Answer (score 5):

Consider the following:

- `fork()` creates only one thread in the child process. You would need to recreate the other threads.
- Mutexes held by other threads in the parent process remain locked forever in the child process because the owning threads do not survive `fork()`. Callbacks registered with `pthread_atfork()` could release the mutexes, but majority of libraries never bother using `pthread_atfork()`. In other words, you child process could hang forever when calling `malloc()` or `new` because the standard heap allocator does use mutexes.

In the light of the above, the only robust option in a multi-threaded process is to call `fork()` and then `exec()`.

Note that your parent process is not affected by `fork()` as long as `pthread_atfork()` handlers are not used.

---

Regarding forking and `boost::asio`, there is [`io_service::notify_fork()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/notify_fork.html) function that needs to be called before forking in the parent and after forking in both parent and child. What it does ultimately depends on the reactor being used. For Linux/UNIX reactors `select_reactor`, `epoll_reactor`, `dev_poll_reactor`, `kqueue_reactor` this function does not do anything to the parent before of after fork, but in the child it recreates the reactor state and re-registers the file descriptors. I am not sure what it does on Windows, though.

An example of its usage can be found in [process_per_connection.cpp](https://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/libs/asio/example/cpp03/fork/process_per_connection.cpp), you can just copy it:

```
void handle_accept(const boost::system::error_code& ec)
{
  if (!ec)
  {
    // Inform the io_service that we are about to fork. The io_service cleans
    // up any internal resources, such as threads, that may interfere with
    // forking.
    io_service_.notify_fork(boost::asio::io_service::fork_prepare);

    if (fork() == 0)
    {
      // Inform the io_service that the fork is finished and that this is the
      // child process. The io_service uses this opportunity to create any
      // internal file descriptors that must be private to the new process.
      io_service_.notify_fork(boost::asio::io_service::fork_child);

      // The child won't be accepting new connections, so we can close the
      // acceptor. It remains open in the parent.
      acceptor_.close();

      // The child process is not interested in processing the SIGCHLD signal.
      signal_.cancel();

      start_read();
    }
    else
    {
      // Inform the io_service that the fork is finished (or failed) and that
      // this is the parent process. The io_service uses this opportunity to
      // recreate any internal resources that were cleaned up during
      // preparation for the fork.
      io_service_.notify_fork(boost::asio::io_service::fork_parent);

      socket_.close();
      start_accept();
    }
  }
  else
  {
    std::cerr << "Accept error: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
    start_accept();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've read that the only reason to `fork` is to then call `exec`, and this is what I am trying to do. However, I don't really understand the correct way to do this when using Boost Asio in a multithreaded program. If I understand correctly, the state of mutexes in the child process doesn't really matter, since I am going to replace the program using `exec`. I am more concerned with the state of the parent process and the state of the `io_service` + I/O objects there.

Comment: So, maybe you have a bit more information on this topic. As it now stands, the answer doesn't really address the question - _how_ do I call `fork` + `exec` in a correct way?

Comment: @villintehaspam Your parent process is not affected as long as `pthread_atfork()` handlers are not used.

Comment: Are you saying that it is safe to avoid calling `notify_fork()` entirely? Since Boost Asio uses `epoll`/`kqueue` internally, don´t these have file descriptors that need to be closed in the child process? Otherwise, wouldn't their continued existence in the child process affect the parent?

Comment: @villintehaspam Just close all file descriptors before `exec()`. Even if they are not closed, that won't affect the parent because your child process is unlikely to examine and poke around each possible file descriptor it might have derived from the parent.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you recommend to not call `notify_fork()` at all and instead to make sure to either have marked all descriptors as "close on exec" or explicitly close them in the child? My concern is about the state of internally used objects within Boost Asio that I have no control over, and the risk that if they are inherited to child processes they might not be kept alive longer than needed. This is an actual problem for sockets at least (that I do have control over), if a socket is inherited, the socket might not close properly and might cause issues in the parent.

Comment: @villintehaspam Added a note regarding `boost::asio` for you.